# Putting everything in the relationships model or adding a new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, entity-relationship

I followed the Michael Hartle book Rails Tutorial and made a user following system that works through a relationships table, with a `follower_id` and a `followed_id`.

I want to add another relationship, this time a favoriting system. Would I be best to add the column to the relationships table and use that or should I create a new model to hold the favoriting relationship?

Comment: Please elaborate your question if u want to create relationship between two models user and favourite ?

Comment: follow this link you will get everything here about relationship    [Rails Relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I'm remade the question over here because I actually tried it out, appreciate any insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a definite answer to your question.

But to keep things simple I would consider to use only one `Connection` table with flags

- `is_followed`
- `is_favorite`

Especially if you can only favorite followed people, validation becomes a lot easier. Still allows easy accessors in your model

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  has_many :favorites, :through => :connections, :conditions => { :is_favorite => true }, :source => ...
  has_many :followers, :through => :connections, :conditions => { :is_followed => true }, :source => ...
  has_many :followee,  :through => :connections, :conditions => { :is_followed => true }, :source => ...
```

Answer (score -1):

and by the way the foreign key relation you can declare is the u have to write t.reference:user in the favourite migration file if u want user foreign key as column in the favourite table

Comment: I've adding the code with what happened here and would appreciate and help with it, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755887/rails-actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclasscl