# Rails :ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, entity-relationship, relationship

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MetaSearch “undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class” for global bar search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147693/metasearch-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass-for-global-bar-sea)

This is the error I'm getting using my updated code when I try going to a user's profile or a individual posts (/posts/1). Its weird that its trying to access the unlike partial anyway because its a new user without any likes.

I've got the code exactly as it shows in the tutorial I used to do this with following users. It works fine for users following users, but I've set it up trying to do with users liking posts.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
    1: <%= form_for(current_user.appreciations.find_by_liked_id(@user),
    2:                                    :html => { :method => :delete },
    3:                                 :remote => true) do |f| %>
    4:   <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Unlike" %></div>
  app/views/users/_unlike.html.erb:1:in     `_app_views_users__unlike_html_erb___769256097635878617_2160255900__1293121959744503098'
  app/views/users/_like_form.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users__like_form_html_erb___3308190581058867471_2162903180_52867338942162503'
  app/views/posts/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb___3188789470217885182_2183453320__3624460432667345580'
```

Here's the pastie with just about everything, if I missed something just let me know. I really appreciate the insight to get this working.

http://pastie.org/1824955

Answer (score 0):

Nothing assigns a value to the `@post` variable.  You have not posted the code for the view(s) that include(s) any of the partials above, but I assume you are iterating over the posts in `@posts`, probably assigning each one to a local variable called `post`.  You should presumably be passing that `post` variable to the partial as a local `..., :locals => {:post => post}`, and then referring to `post`, not `@post` within the partials.

Comment: I've added the user's show view above, sorry about that it was very late when I posted this question. I'm still confused about where I'm assigning each one to a local variable called post? And where do i put that :locals => code to pass the post variable to the partials as local?

Comment: I tried adding  <%= render 'users/like_form', :locals => {:post => post} if user_signed_in? %> to my _post.html.erb but the variable isn't being passed back :(

Comment: Shouldn't that be <%= render :partial => 'users/like_form', ... ?

Comment: Yes i did try that, and after it not working i rolled back my commit and started over, this time I got a different error. I've included all my code, appreciate any help. Thanks.